# Rotate MovieClip 90 Degrees on Y-Axis ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, adobe, 3d, actionscript-3

I am really confused trying to understand the basics of how 3d works in Flash and ActionScript.

I think by explaining how I could do the following that might make things a bit clearer.

I have created a green rectangle in a MovieClip and assign it a class. I then create several instances of this class on the stage. If I put them in a line across the screen and set the `rotationY` property to 90 on all of them they all look different. They look like they would if you were looking at them through a camera.

This is the actionscript code:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public function Main() {

            for (var i:uint=0; i<21; i++)
            {
                var obj = new Test();
                obj.y = 300;
                obj.x = i * 80;
                obj.rotationY = 90;
                addChild(obj);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is a screenshot of the output:
[image: screenshot 1]

This is a screenshot of the MovieClip:
[image: screenshot 2]

**How would I go about arranging these on the screen so that they all appeared side on (like one bang in the centre would)?** I effectively want to disable looking at it through a camera.

Likewise does this mean that even objects that are on the stage that have a y rotation of 0 are also being treated like they are in a 3d space and rotated slightly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found http://backroom.bostonproductions.com/?p=761 which explains it pretty well.

> This is because the 90-degree rotation is in relation to the vanishing
>   point of the stage, (which can be set using the 3D transform tool in
>   the IDE). The vanishing point will affect all of your display objects
>   by default, causing the 3D rotation to be a product of the vanishing
>   point. But what if you don’t want your display object to rotate in 3D
>   space in accordance with the vanishing point? What if you want to
>   rotate your square 90 degrees and see a square rotated 90 degrees,
>   regardless of its location on the stage? You can deal with this using
>   ActionScript 3 and PerspectiveProjection. By transforming the
>   PerspectiveProjection of your square and setting the projection center
>   to the X and Y position of your square, you can now rotate it
>   independent of the stage’s vanishing point.

So each MovieClip needs to be assigned its own PerspectiveProjection object.

Also elements are only converted to 3d (automatically) when their x or y rotation or z position is set as described at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS7D38179D-58B9-409c-9E5C-257DDECB1A02.html

> When you explicitly set the z property of a display object to a
>   numeric value, the object automatically creates a 3D transformation
>   matrix. You can alter this matrix to modify the 3D transformation
>   settings of that object.
>
> In addition, 3D rotation differs from 2D rotation. In 2D the axis of
>   rotation is always perpendicular to the x/y plane - in other words, on
>   the z-axis. In 3D the axis of rotation can be around any of the x, y,
>   or z axes. Setting the rotation and scaling properties of a display
>   object enable it to move in 3D space.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well done on finding the solution and thanks for posting back. Remember to accept your answer so the question can be marked as answered.